# What does the Qur'an say about interracial marriages?

Tags: quran, nikah

Moses' wife was of another race and in the Bible ([Numbers 12:1-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+12%3A1-15&version=NIV)) Aaron and Miriam were punished for criticizing this interracial marriage.  What does the Qur'an say about interracial marriages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Quran, Allah said:

> يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنَّا خَلَقْنَاكُم مِّن ذَكَرٍ وَأُنثَى وَجَعَلْنَاكُمْ شُعُوبًا وَقَبَائِلَ لِتَعَارَفُوا إِنَّ أَكْرَمَكُمْ عِندَ اللَّهِ أَتْقَاكُمْ إِنَّ اللَّهَ عَلِيمٌ خَبِيرٌ
>
> O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted. [Quran 49:13]

Allah clearly encourages us to *knowing one another* as stated in the verse. One of the ways of knowing other people and races is marriage.

Also, Prophet Mohammed (PBUH) Married to different women from different races and tribes and religions. Maria (RA) was [Coptic (Native Egyptian)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copts) and she was Christian (Converted to Islam later), Safia (RA) was Jewish from [Israelites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israelites) (Also converted to Islam).

As long as Allah encourages knowing other races and Mohammed (PBUH) married to another races, then it is something actually not only allowed but also recommended for Muslims.

Answer (score 8):

in sura Al-Hujurat:13

> يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنَّا خَلَقْنَاكُم مِّن ذَكَرٍ وَأُنثَىٰ
>   وَجَعَلْنَاكُمْ شُعُوبًا وَقَبَائِلَ لِتَعَارَفُوا إِنَّ أَكْرَمَكُمْ
>   عِندَ اللَّـهِ أَتْقَاكُمْ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ عَلِيمٌ خَبِيرٌ
>
> O men, We created you from a male and female, and formed you into
>   nations and tribes that you may recognize each other. He who has more
>   integrity has indeed greater honor with God. Surely God is
>   all-knowing and well-informed.

This indicates that it is not preferred between one interracial over another only piety and belief
And Islam encourage acquaintance and love between the interracial

Of course, with the condition of the same religion
Depending on the Al-Baqara:221

> وَلَا تَنكِحُوا الْمُشْرِكَاتِ حَتَّىٰ يُؤْمِنَّ ۚ وَلَأَمَةٌ
>   مُّؤْمِنَةٌ خَيْرٌ مِّن مُّشْرِكَةٍ وَلَوْ أَعْجَبَتْكُمْ ۗ وَلَا
>   تُنكِحُوا الْمُشْرِكِينَ حَتَّىٰ يُؤْمِنُوا ۚ وَلَعَبْدٌ مُّؤْمِنٌ
>   خَيْرٌ مِّن مُّشْرِكٍ وَلَوْ أَعْجَبَكُمْ ۗ أُولَـٰئِكَ يَدْعُونَ
>   إِلَى النَّارِ ۖ وَاللَّـهُ يَدْعُو إِلَى الْجَنَّةِ وَالْمَغْفِرَةِ
>   بِإِذْنِهِ ۖ وَيُبَيِّنُ آيَاتِهِ لِلنَّاسِ لَعَلَّهُمْ يَتَذَكَّرُونَ
>
> Do not marry idolatrous women unless they join the faith. A maid
>   servant who is a believer is better than an idolatress even though you
>   may like her. And do not marry your daughters to idolaters until they
>   accept the faith. A servant who is a believer is better than an
>   idolater even though you may like him. They invite you to Hell, but
>   God calls you to Paradise and pardon by His grace. And He makes His
>   signs manifest that men may haply take heed.

Knowing that the islam (sharee'ah) has Allowed to Muslim men marriage from non-Muslim women, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has been answered already but just a side note - the story of Bilal RA is a beautiful story, how he began as a slave and ended up being one of the most trusted and loyal of companions to the Prophet pbuh as a man of Abyssinian (Ethiopian) decent. He also went on to become the first Muaddhin (caller to prayer) in Islam. To me, giving such a man such status shows how Islam tried to eradicate racism and show us that no man is better than another man except in piety.

Answer (score -2):

The Quran had nothing Against Interracial marriage your encouraged to marry somewith with good Iman above all things .  but I would like to advise you that it is a test in its own way.